# Skip figures while replacing text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I need to replace the text on the paragraphs while keeping the figures that are inline with text in place while also keeping the old text's style.

The input consists of a line of text with a picture in the middle, for example:

`OLD TEXT (picture.jpg) OLD TEXT`

The output should be, for example:

`NEW TEXT (picture.jpg) NEW TEXT`

So far I've gotten to:

```
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    for run in para.runs:
        if (run.text != ""):
            run.text = "NEW TEXT"
```

But it adds an extra NEW TEXT string for the picture.jpg object and doesn't keep the style (bold/italic, text identation, font, etc.).

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave us more here.  How about a small sample dataset from 'before' and then a small sample of the desired 'after' dataset.

Comment: Can you share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Added example, sorry guys.